# Why is it difficult to get white light sources that maintain a constant phase difference?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference, coherence

In my text book the explanation for the question is this (Collins Year 1 and AS level physics):

> It is difficult to get white light sources that maintain a constant phase difference.Light is emitted in very short bursts, which have random phase and random polarisation.

I don't understand how the 'light being emitted in short bursts' can affect the phase difference and polarisation and thus affect the white light source's coherency.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words in yellow don't make much sense, as you indicate.

Think microscopically. Unless you have a laser or some similar coherent source, emissions will be at different wavelengths by different molecules or atoms and so on, and if you mix enough emitters in they'll approximate white light, as a mix of different wavelengths. The different emitters will emit randomly with respect to each other, and thus not in phase.

The exception is when the different microscopic emitters in the body sending the light out as somehow synchronized. That's what happens in a laser, where the stimulated emission causes as large number of microscopic emitters to emit in sync. And it is then the same type of microscopic emitter, and so the same wavelength also. If they start in phase, and they bounce around the fiber little enough, they'll stay in sync, i.e., same phase.

Comment: What do you mean by "The different emitters will emit randomly with respect to each other, and thus not in phase"?

Comment: Microscopic emmiters like molecules and atoms emit based on random disturbances. Only if they are stimulated by an external coherent field will they do otherwise. Normally is thermal and rando motion. If it's heating in a wire in a lightbulb it's random and all crews to look white. If coherent it's one freq thru say laser stimulation and then coherent